# Pass values from one method to use them in another method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

How can I use values from the `timer_lights_status_Tick` method in `groupBox1_Paint`?

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Here is where I want to use those variables: red_light1, yellow_light1…
}

public void timer_lights_status_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int red_light1, yellow_light1, green_light1,
        red_light2, yellow_light2, green_light2;

    red_light1    = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));
    yellow_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 33));
    green_light1  = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 34));

    red_light2    = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 35));
    yellow_light2 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 36));
    green_light2  = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 37));
}
```

Comment: Move the "int red_light1"... outside of the function. You will also need to call this.Invalidate() after setting all the lights in the timer tick to trigger a redraw.

Comment: I moved that line. You say to call "this.Invalidate()" to work like a reset?

Comment: Its not a reset so-to-speak, but it informs the control that it needs to redraw its client area, which in turn calls your paint method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable outside of the Timer.Tick event so that you can access

Refresh the combobox on the timer event itself when the value changes

```
private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

  //Now those variables can be accessed here.

}

int red_light1,yellow_light1,green_light1,
       red_light2,yellow_light2,green_light2;

public void timer_lights_status_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    red_light1    = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));
    yellow_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 33));
    green_light1  = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 34));

    red_light2    = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 35));
    yellow_light2 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 36));
    green_light2  = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 37));

    groupBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Declare variables outside function scope. 
// This way, any function can access and modify these same variables.
int red_light1,yellow_light1,green_light1,
red_light2,yellow_light2,green_light2; 

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

  // Do something with variables: red_light1,yellow_light1... that you declared before
  // ex.:
  // red_light1 = 10;
  // CallAnotherFunction(red_light1);

}


public void timer_lights_status_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    red_light1    = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));
    yellow_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 33));
    green_light1  = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 34));

    red_light2    = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 35));
    yellow_light2 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 36));
    green_light2  = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 37));
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did and why you did it. For people without programming experience (who are learning to code) only the source code is not sufficient. An alternative would be to write a comment in the code, something like `// global variables, used to exchange the values between methods`. A short explanation what a global variable is, would be great.